# get cursor row and column in a content-editable div

Tags: javascript

There are several recipes for finding the cursor position as the user types text in a content-editable div, but I can't get any of them to work.  In fact, I get the most surprising results from the simplest code; if, in this following snippet, you add some text and then backspace to remove it, your startoffset actually increments!  (I can imagine its splitting elements or something and the offset includes non-printable tags or something.)

I have a div that will have a fixed font but which I plan to add syntax highlighting to (its not something codemirror can just do; its more interactive prompt with editing anywhere in the script if that kind of makes sense why I am want to get the position myself.)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ta = null;

function onKeypress(event) {
    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    document.getElementById("msg").textContent = ""+range.startContainer+","+range.startOffset;
}

function init() {
    ta = document.getElementById("ta");
    ta.focus();
    ta.onkeypress = onKeypress;
}
//-->
</script>
<body onload="init();">
<noscript>
Sorry, you need javascript.  Not much to see here otherwise; move along.
</noscript>
<p id="msg"></p><hr/>
<div id="ta" contenteditable="true" style="width:100%; height:100%; font-family: courier;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I know the row and column, and get the text for any row, in such a content-editable div?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying is wrong with your code. When I test your example code in Chrome, the code seems to work - when I backspace the position display doesn't update until I start typing more text into the div, but then the position display is correct again. Is the problem that backspace isn't triggering the keyup event, or something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Upon changing the onkeypress to an onkeydown (so that backspace is captured) I see that the position display increments once when a backspace is entered.

Forgive me if I've got the wrong end of the stick, but I believe one solution is doing the following:

```
var ta = null;
var range = null;

function onKeyDown(event) {
    if(event.which != 8 && event.which != 46) {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        document.getElementById("msg").textContent = ""+range.startContainer+","+range.startOffset;
    }
}

function onKeyUp(event) {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    document.getElementById("msg").textContent = ""+range.startContainer+","+range.startOffset;
}

function init() {
    ta = document.getElementById("ta");
    ta.focus();
    ta.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
    ta.onkeyup = onKeyUp;
}
```

Comment: what happens if you press the enter key?

Comment: It starts counting again from zero. there is nothing in your code to display which row the cursor is on.

Comment: but that's the bigger question!  "How can I know the row and column, and get the text for any row, in such a content-editable div?".  As this is like a rich text editor, every time the user presses a key I want to know what line they are on and what the line contents are.

Comment: Ah, well from your question and code, I took it to mean that you were having no problems with the row position. I suggest you find a script that gives you the cursor position in the entire string, then count the linebreaks in the string up to that position - that's your row count. Then you count how many characters are between the cursor and the last linebreak - your column count. A quick search led me to this code which gives you cursor position in the string http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=109&Desc=Cursor-Position-in-Textbox-Using-JavaScript (ignore the html)

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using textboxes instead of divs?

```
<textbox>edit my content</textbox>
```

If you must use a div you can get and update its contents with the innerHTML property

```
alert(document.getElementById('theIdOfMyDiv').innerHTML);
```

or to add content

```
var currentContent = document.getElementById('theIdOfMyDiv').innerHTML;
currentContent = currentContent + 'add some content';
```